# What is "Default Notification Light"?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Several question have been asked on SO about the use of Lights in Notification and I have trying to find the answer myself for hours now. Android documentation for Notification states

> public static final int DEFAULT_LIGHTS
>
> Since: API Level 1 Use the default notification lights. This will
>   ignore the FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS bit, and ledARGB, ledOffMS, or ledOnMS.

**My Question**

1. What are the **default notification lights** as per documentation?
2. Does screen shows a flash of light for few milliseconds on lights notification or it for LED only?
3. Does every Android phone has LED on them?
4. Does Samsung Galaxy Ace has LED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The device's default notification light.
2. No.
3. Absolutely not; Samsungs in particular often don't. *Very* irritating.
4. I don't believe so. There are apps that work around this in various ways; YMMV.

Comment: +1, Thanks.Can you suggest some code snippet for work around? (Should I ask separate question for it) and what is YMMV?...:)

Comment: @codingcrow "Your Mileage May Vary". Some use the screen, don't know what other options there are except maybe the camera flash.